# I have an assignment asking me to code a horoscope with user input, not working

Tags: java, string, input

I've got an assignment asking me to write a code that goes off of what the user inputs numerically (month and day, e.g. January = 1, January 5 = 1/5), and my code takes the number they input and changes it into words. For example, if they input 4 and 7 for month and day,my code turns it into April seventh for output.

My problem is when I run the program the program asks for the month and after any input, even if it is January second, the output says "December thirty-first". I think it's because that's the last thing I coded in, but if I do else if statements, it tells me "else without if" and won't compile.

Here is the beginning of the code (months go on in the same manner as the first two, then change to days that also carry on like the months do.

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

  class Assignment2Try2{
    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     int numberMonth = 0; 
     int numberDay = 0;
     String month = "";
     String day = "";

     System.out.println( "What month were you born in? (number)" ); 
     numberMonth = scan.nextInt();
     if (numberMonth == 1);
     {
       month = "January";
     }
     if (numberMonth == 2);
     {
       month = "Febuary";
     }
```

And for the days, it looks like this and goes through the 31st for every month to make it easier to code:

```
     if (numberDay == 1);
     {
       day = "first";
     }
     if (numberDay == 2);
     {
       day = "second";
     }
     if (numberDay == 3);
     {
       day = "third";
     }
```

in this form, it compiles, but just prints "December thirty-first" every time, no matter the input, and doesn't ask for day input, just month. I think it might be something wrong with my final System.out.println , which looks like this:

```
System.out.println( "Your birthday is: " + month + " " + day);
```

I'm confused as to why the compiler runs it to only output "December thirty-first" because the month code doesn't seem to be wrong, and neither does the code for the days.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to put the code here, but only the relevant parts of the code (the ones you're having problems with).

Comment: It's a good idea to post well-formatted pertinent code as well as all error messages and descriptions of behavioral problems. Else it will be hard to know what you may be doing wrong. Please have a look at the [tour], [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Javascript and compiler-error tags removed. Please stick with only relevant tags. I've also deleted the part about due date as it's not relevant to the problem. You're going to have to post more relevant code, as I don't think that we can see the source of the error with what you're posting.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, that took me a while, too ;-)
You have too much semicolons. Remove all of the semicolons after the if

```
 if(month == 1);
               ^
```

These ones.